# Enable scrollviewer to scroll per item instead of default behaviour

Tags: c#, wpf

In my current project i have a scroll viewer that has several buttons listed.
Instead of navigating trough the standard scrollbar navigation buttons are used instead.

So what i wish to achieve is when i press a navigation button (repeat button) the next button / item in line directly pops up.

With the default behaviour i see the content slowly appearing when i press the navigation button.

When i click next or previous on the navigation i want to see the next item in line instantly appearing insteed of waiting for example 2 sec until the scrolling is done.

Inside the scrollviewer is a itemsControl that contains a stackpanel with custom created buttons.

The scrollviewer is on its turn located in a grid.

Or is a scrollviewer not the way to go to navigate between items in a stackpanel by means of 2 navigation buttons?

EDIT: For some reason logical scrolling seems not to be working anymore after applying a itemControl where the stackpanel and the button datatemplate is located.

Thanks in advance!
Jackz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is called logical scrolling. To enable it, you have to put your ScrollViewer in a StackPanel and set the ScrollViewer's "CanContentScroll" property to true.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/214442/A-Scrolling-Area-with-Only-Scroll-Buttons) you find more info.

Comment: I actually based my control on this very example you mentioned! My layout is pretty much exactly the same and CanContentScroll is set to true. Although it does not scroll like in that example with one button at a time when pressing navigation. Regards.